# read data by NSURLSession on tableview

Tags: ios

I try to read data by using NSURLSession and return on tableview but even my code adds data in viewArray the

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [viewArray count];
}
```

returns 0!, here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    viewArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil ];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pizzy.sadrcom.com/foodCategories/pizzas/margarita"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
        for (NSDictionary* groups in json ) {
            GroupData *gInfo = [[GroupData alloc] init];
            // Title
            gInfo.title    = [groups objectForKey:@"Title"];
            // The Id
            gInfo.theId  = [groups objectForKey:@"Id"];

            [viewArray addObject:gInfo];
        }

    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling     `[tableView reloadData];`  after adding object to array, and as you are getting data async then first time your numberOfRowsInSection will call before data received.
do something like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    viewArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil ];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pizzy.sadrcom.com/foodCategories/pizzas/margarita"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);
    for (NSDictionary* groups in json ) {
        GroupData *gInfo = [[GroupData alloc] init];
        // Title
        gInfo.title    = [groups objectForKey:@"Title"];
        // The Id
        gInfo.theId  = [groups objectForKey:@"Id"];
        [viewArray addObject:gInfo];

    }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [tableView reloadData];
            });
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

That is because response comes later than interface is created. Try this

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    viewArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];//replace your initialisation with this. Yours is uglier

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pizzy.sadrcom.com/foodCategories/pizzas/margarita"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
        for (NSDictionary* groups in json ) {
            GroupData *gInfo = [[GroupData alloc] init];
            // Title
            gInfo.title    = [groups objectForKey:@"Title"];
            // The Id
            gInfo.theId  = [groups objectForKey:@"Id"];

            [viewArray addObject:gInfo];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [yourTable reloadData];//replace yourTable with your table variable.
            });

        }

    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```